# List<SelectListItem> with selected SelectListItem is not selected in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlistitem

I am having a List of `SelectedListItem` and I am sending it from controller to view using ViewBag.
And there is one SelectedListItem with `selected = true` attribute inside the List.

In view the code is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Configuration, 
new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfConfigValues,"Value", "Text"),
new { @class = "ddl", @id = "ddlForConfiguration"})
```

I am also passing the value which I want to be shown selected, inside the `model.Configuration`.

I know we can pass the selected index along with `Value`, `Text`.

In controller I am setting the `ViewBag` as

```
ViewBag.ListOfConfigValues = defaultObj.configurationsList;
                return PartialView(detail);
```

`configurationList` is as follows

```
{Text = "Red", Value = "Color1", Selected = false},
{Text = "Blue", Value = "Color2", Selected = true},
{Text = "Green", Value = "Color3", Selected = false}
```

Comment: Show the controller's code where you populate the `ViewBag.ListOfConfigValues` and the `Configuration` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your selected value to `model.Configuration` property.

`DropDownListFor` will only work with `selected = true` element if your `Configuration` property will be `Nullable` type and be `null` at the moment, else `DropDownListFor` set selected value from `Configuration` property value.

**EDIT:**

Your `selectListItem` should be `value = "Red" and text = "Red"`

**Or**

```
Model.Configuration = "Color1"
```

`DropDownListFor` set value depends on `Value` property, not on `Text`

Comment: Hello @Teo actually Model.Configuration = "Red" and selectListItem value = "Color1" and text = "Red". If I set value = "Red" too then its all working good.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to implement in this way only. Not comfortable but okay. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: np, try it and say what is your final result please.

Comment: Yup its working pretty good to me. Rest there must be an option to set selected item on the basis of text not only by value.